# Refactor switch statement that assigns different variables depending on case?

Tags: c#, refactoring

How can I refactor a switch statement that is in multiple places in code that assigns a value to a variable depending on which case is thrown, for example:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

switch(c)
{
   case "1"
      a = 1;
      break;
   case "2"
      b = 2;
      break;

}
```

In the above example, resharper will use one of the variables as the return and the other as an out parameter.  Is there another way to do it, maybe not extracting out the whole switch block.

Comment: Are the initial values *always* 0?

Comment: @Jon Skeet.  Yes the initial values are always 0.

Comment: And are the two values related? Might it be worth encapsulating them in a struct or class?

Comment: Well, to me they are related.  To be a little bit more descriptive, one is the Minimum Length of stay required at a hotel room and one is a Maximum Length of Stay required at a hotel room.  An xml message will have the contain the type of variable to set.  For example, if the message contains SetMinLOS, then the Minimum Length of Stay Variable is set.  If the message contains SetMaxLos, then the Maximum Length of Variable is set.  This is in a foreach loop because their can be multiple Lengths of Stay

Comment: I like the idea of a class or struct here if it suits well.  Would the method to assign and return the correct value be defined in the new class.  Also, is there a preference to a struct or class here?

Comment: It would return a new instance, probably. I typically use a class rather than a struct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code block has a couple of different ways of refactoring it to make it more reusable without having it copied over in places. However, they're going to require reworks of things:

*Are the objects logically grouped somehow?*

If so, then you could make an object to represent them, and then refactor to return the object set with values.

```
 var myObj = SetObjectAccordingTo(c);

 protected SomeObj SetObjectAccordingTo(string c)
 {
      var myObj = new SomeObj();

      switch(c)
      {
            case "1": myObj.a = 1;
                break;
            case "2": myObj.b = 2;
                break;
      }

      return myObj;
 }
```

*If they are not logically grouped, and each is assigned a value...*

Then logic for determining each value needs to be split.

```
 a = DetermineValueForA(c);
 b = DetermineValueForB(c);
```

And each method deals only with the cases where a is involved.

*If they are not logically grouped, and only certain values are assigned...*

Then there is not much optimization that can be performed save moving the respective values to member variables and then calling each with that specific method.

If you could provide a sample of what you're trying to do, we could offer a solution more than likely.

Comment: Does the comment added below my post help.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you need to send different requests to different handlers; a `SetMinLos` request should go to a different handler so you have one handler per operation.

Comment: I like what you have done here.  So the method to assign and return the correct value would not be on the object set, the object set would just contain the two or more variables.  The only thing I would ask is that I have heard that it isn't good practice to use a class when you only have a some properties.  Is this an exception or would a struct be a better?

Comment: In your situation, `struct` is probably better. However, that's going to depend on your uses of the values.

Comment: Another question, lets assume that I have two more related variables that aren't related to the previous two, could I just add them to the SomeObj class and set them instead of creating a class only for related variables?

Comment: You'd only do that if you were lazy =D - if they are unrelated, they should have their own type. I'd definitely recommend moving to a handler / request type, or processing based on the existence of XML nodes via a wrapper.

Comment: Ok, Tejs.  Thanks for the valuable input.  One of the problems is not really knowing what is and is not related from a subject matter point of view :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean you'd like to extract this as a method? You might consider returning a struct (or perhaps a class) if A and B are related in some manner. Perhaps, NDA permitting, you could show us a code fragment in context so it might become clearer how to solve this.

Comment: Yes, Extract as a method that will return A or B depending on the value of C.  What is NDA?

Comment: NDA stands for Non-Disclosure Agreement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement

Comment: A method cannot return two things without using the out keyword. Once again, the only way to avoid this is to either return an existing type or define your own.

Comment: I commented under the post with a better example.